# Safety of using reflect.StringHeader in Go?

Tags: go, cgo

I have a small function which passes the pointer of Go string data to C (Lua library):

```golang
func (L *C.lua_State) pushLString(s string) {
    gostr := (*reflect.StringHeader)(unsafe.Pointer(&s))
    C.lua_pushlstring(L, (*C.char)(unsafe.Pointer(gostr.Data)), C.ulong(gostr.Len))
    // lua_pushlstring copies the given string, not keeping the original pointer.
}
```

It works in simple tests, but from the documentations it's unclear whether this is safe at all.

According to [Go document](https://golang.org/pkg/unsafe/), the memory of `reflect.StringHeader` should be pinned for *gostr*, but the `Stringheader.Data` is already a `uintptr`, *"an integer value with no pointer semantics"* - which is itself odd because if it has no pointer semantics, wouldn't the field be completely useless as the memory may be moved right after the value is read? Or is the field treated specially like `reflect.Value.Pointer`? Or perhaps there is a different way of getting C pointer from string?

Comment: > wouldn't the field be completely useless as the memory may be moved right after the value is read?

Yes, so you need to avoid that by keeping some other, "real" (ie. tracked by the garbage collector as a Go value) reference to the string's underlying array for as long you want the StringHeader.Data pointer to remain valid.

Comment: The `gostr` there keeps the reference to go string, but how would that keep go from relocating `StringHeader.Data` in future? From godoc

1. Pointer represented by `uintptr` is not traced or taken into account by GC
2. StringHeader.Data is a `uintptr`.

There are examples in godoc using it but it doesn't make any sense according to godoc...

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice this bit: "lua_pushlstring copies the given string, not keeping the original pointer." I'd say you're good not because of `gostr`, but because of `s`, which is a live reference for as long as the function runs. If Lua copies the string in that interval, then it lives long enough.

Answer (score 1):

> it's unclear whether this is safe at all.

Q4 2022: Tapir Liui (https://twitter.com/TapirLiu/) dans Go101 (https://github.com/go101/go101) gives a clue as to the "safety" of [reflect.StringHeader](https://pkg.go.dev/reflect#StringHeader) in [this tweet](https://twitter.com/go100and1/status/1566723773579292672):

> Since Go 1.20, the [`reflect.StringHeader` and `reflect.SliceHeader` types will be depreciated](https://github.com/golang/go/commit/bc2e961cf4cda945dc6d607a5076b4e376553e9f) and not recommended to be used.
>
> Accordingly, two functions, `unsafe.StringData` and `unsafe.SliceData`, will be introduced in Go 1.20 to take over the use cases of two old reflect types.

That was initially discussed in [CL 401434](https://go-review.googlesource.com/c/go/+/401434), then in [issue 53003](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/53003).

> The reason for deprecation is that `reflect.SliceHeader` and `reflect.StringHeader` are [commonly misused](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/19367).
> As well, the types have always been documented as unstable and not to be relied upon.
>
> We can see in Github [code](https://github.com/search?l=Go&q=reflect.StringHeader&type=Code) [search](https://github.com/search?l=Go&q=reflect.SliceHeader&type=Code) that usage of these types is ubiquitous.
> The most common use cases I've seen are:
>
> - converting `[]byte` to `string`:
>   Equivalent to `*(*string)(unsafe.Pointer(&mySlice))`, which is never actually officially documented anywhere as something that can be relied upon.
>   Under the hood, the shape of a `string` is less than a slice, so this seems valid per unsafe rule.
> - converting `string` to `[]byte`:
>   commonly seen as `*(*[]byte)(unsafe.Pointer(&string))`, which is by-default broken because the `Cap` field can be past the end of a page boundary (example here, in widely used code) -- this violates unsafe rule.
> - grabbing the Data pointer field for ffi or some other niche use converting a slice of one type to a slice of another type

[Ian Lance Taylor](https://github.com/ianlancetaylor) [adds](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/53003#issuecomment-1132392204):

> One of the main use cases of unsafe.Slice is to create a slice whose backing array is a memory buffer returned from C code or from a call such as syscall.MMap.
> I agree that it can be used to (unsafely) convert from a slice of one type to a slice of a different type.

---

Q4 2023: this has been closed/removed from proposal, and [issue 53003](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/53003#issuecomment-1963944804) concludes with:

> Why originally proposed functions `StringToBytes` and `BytesToString` are not added to unsafe package, so people stop writing various implementations with questionable correctness again and again is beyond my comprehension.

With the reply:

> Because:
>
> - `StringToBytes` is now just `unsafe.Slice(unsafe.StringData(s), len(s))` and
> - `BytesToString` is just `unsafe.String(unsafe.SliceData(b), len(b))`,
>
> which are both very easy and there shouldn't be any implementations with questionable correctness.